# Removing an object from an array in Firestore

Tags: arrays, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

I'm just getting into Firebase, and really digging it so far, but I'm having a bit of an issue using a Cloud Function to remove an item from an array in a collection. In the app I'm using, users have a document in a users collection that contains user-specific data that doesn't fit within the authentication model. The data looks like this:

[Screenshot of user collection structure.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DjCnq.png)

(It's a fitness-related app, hence the array being called 'workouts')

The user has the ability to create a workout, and when they do, after it's created, a cloud function watching for new workouts adds the ID of the newly created workout to the user document, appending it to the workouts array using arrayUnion:

```
exports.addWorkoutToAuthorsListOfWorkouts = functions.firestore
    .document('workouts/{workoutId}')
    .onCreate((snap, context) => {
      const id = context.params.workoutId
      const name = snap.data().title
      const uid = snap.data().author

      const workout_reference = { id: id, name: name, uid: uid }
      const workoutsRef = admin.firestore().collection("users").doc(uid)

      return workoutsRef.update({
        workouts: admin.firestore.FieldValue.arrayUnion(workout_reference)
      })
    })
```

This works fine, but I want the user to be able to delete workouts, and I didn't add a string to the workouts array, but instead an object like this:

```
{ id: "1214", name: "My workout", uid: "123asd" }
```

Now, for this exact use-case I could delete the array in my ReactJS app and then do an update, but I'm going to be adding the ability for users to "like" the workouts of other users, which will result in a reference to the workout being added to "workouts" in their personal user document. So if I, as a creator of a workout, delete my workout, I need to be able to delete it from the workouts array of any user who has it. Using arrayRemove didn't work because (I assume) I couldn't pass the object to be removed.

What's the best-practices way to do this? I made this attempt:

```
exports.removeWorkoutFromAuthorsListOfWorkouts = functions.firestore
  .document('workouts/{workoutId}')
  .onDelete((snap, context) => {

    const id =  context.params.workoutId
    const uid = snap.data().author
    const name = snap.data().name
    let newWorkouts = new Array()

    admin.firestore().collection("users").doc(uid).collection("workouts").get().then((querySnapshot) => {
      querySnapshot.forEach((doc: any) => {
          if (doc.id !== id) {
            newWorkouts.push(doc.data())
          }
      });
    });

    const workoutsRef = admin.firestore().collection("users").doc(uid)

    return workoutsRef.update({
      workouts: newWorkouts
    })
  })
```

But Firebase didn't like it at all, and I'm new enough to the platform that I realize this is most likely due to the result of a knowledge gap, rather than any problem with Firestore or Cloud Functions.

Any help you could provide would be very much appreciated. Cheers!

**UPDATE:** Got it working, with the following code:

```
exports.removeWorkoutFromSubscribersListOfWorkouts = functions.firestore
  .document('workouts/{workoutId}')
  .onDelete((snap, context) => {
    const workoutId =  context.params.workoutId
    const subscribers = snap.data().subscribers
    let newWorkouts = new Array()

    subscribers.forEach(subscriber => {
      let userRef = admin.firestore().collection("users").doc(subscriber)

      return userRef.get().then(doc => {
        return userRef.update({
          workouts: doc.data().workouts.filter(workout => workout.id !== workoutId)
        })
      })
    })
    .catch(() => {
      console.log("error")
    })
  })
```

Comment: You're actually not using promises correctly here, and that often has unexpected consequences.  Your call to get() is asynchronous, returning immediately with a promise, and then the code continues without waiting for a result.  Your later call to update() is likely getting executed before your array is populated by the results of the asynchronous query.

Comment: Hey Doug! I've just been watching a bunch of you! 

I thought my use of get() was consistent with Firebase docs, and it's how I'm using it on the frontend, in React. Is a different syntax required if I'm using it in the context of a Cloud function?

This is the specific error the above method returns:
`Error: Invalid use of type "undefined" as a Firestore argument.`

Comment: The syntax for promises is the same everywhere. It's just that you're not making your code wait for the async work to complete before moving on to the next stage.

Comment: Ahhhh, right. That's an embarrassing oversight on my part. Thanks!

Comment: How does firestore have no method delete objects within arrays? This is a hack at best.